# js/jquery get value from input text return "empty string"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm facing an issue with the getting of an input type text.

The input is in a slider supported by swiper, each slide is called with ajax to get the proper template and each slide have inputs, and I need to get the values of those inputs.

It's working for radio or checkboxes as the value is set in html, but not for text when the value is typed by the user.

Here is the html of the template with the text field

I also tried with native js and others events (change, keyup), it's like if I was unable to read the value of the text field.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.swiper-button-next', function() {
  console.log($('#surface-checked-4').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-slide">
  <div class="multistep__content">
    <div class="value-multistep">
      <h2 class="title title-huge value-question">Quelle surface&nbsp;?</h2>
      <div class="value-input form__input-wrapper form__input-wrapper--value">
        <div class="input" id="input-surface-4">
          <input id="surface-checked-4" type="text" name="surface-habitable" placeholder="Surface habitable" class="form__input input__field get-value" value="" />
          <label for="surface-checked-4" class="form__label input__label">Surface habitable</label>
          <p class="form__error" id="surface-4"></p>
          <span class="input__unit">m<sup>2</sup></span>
          <button class="swiper-button-next">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="value-help">
        <i class="value-help__icon icon-info"></i>
        <p class="value-help__text">
          <strong>Surface habitable</strong> Prendre en compte la surface de plancher construite dont les hauteurs sous-plafond sont supérieures à 1,80m (= surface Carrez). Les garages, celliers, abris de jardin... sont à exclure.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to actually ADD the `<button class="swiper-button-next">Next</button>` but then the code works

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issue with your code. I tried this and its working. Please check below. Try by clicking on next button

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.swiper-button-next', function () {
    alert($('#surface-checked-4').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="multistep__content">
        <div class="value-multistep">
            <h2 class="title title-huge value-question">Quelle surface&nbsp;?</h2>
            <div class="value-input form__input-wrapper form__input-wrapper--value">
                <div class="input" id="input-surface-4">
                    <input id="surface-checked-4" type="text" name="surface-habitable" placeholder="Surface habitable" class="form__input input__field get-value" value="" />
                    <label for="surface-checked-4" class="form__label input__label">Surface habitable</label>
<button class="swiper-button-next">Next</button>
                    <p class="form__error" id="surface-4"></p>
                    <span class="input__unit">m<sup>2</sup></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="value-help">
                <i class="value-help__icon icon-info"></i>
                <p class="value-help__text">
                    <strong>Surface habitable</strong>
                    Prendre en compte la surface de plancher construite dont les hauteurs sous-plafond sont supérieures à 1,80m (= surface Carrez). Les garages, celliers, abris de jardin... sont à exclure.
                </p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The template with the text field is not just in the html page. It is called with ajax, at the first loading of the page, the template and the field does not exist.
I thinks the issue is due to that, but I can't find how to fix it.

The code with the .val() function is as I dropped it here, it's not working that easy